# Отправка формы на свой ресурс после отправки на приемщик данных Тильды

Tags: javascript, html, tilda

Есть люди, которые с тильдой работали. Я в `js` не сильно шарю, отсюда неполное понимание [примеров](http://help-ru.tilda.ws/tips/javascript).

Есть `js-form-proccess`. Мне не понятно, что это такое и какую роль это играет в работе тильды. Т.е. кто и как создаёт на странице `js-form-proccess`.

Откуда на странице берётся `js-form-process`?

Для примера, на [лендинге](https://casecopilot.com/) не удаётся после отправки формы на приёмщик тильды отправить всё на мой ресурс. Отправкой занимается скрипт, который можно найти по `js-form-process`.

С другой стороны, на [лендинге](https://www.edu.fless.pro/case-copilot-en) Всё корректно работает. Отправкой занимается скрипт, который можно найти по `js-form-process`.

Мне не ясно, откуда берётся `js-form-proccess` и кто его генерирует. Почему на одних лендингах он есть автоматом, а на других — нет.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь несколько вопросов в одном, отвечу хотя бы частично, потом можно будет уточнить.

В примере по ссылке `js-form-proccess` встречается в таком контексте:

```
$('.js-form-proccess').each(function () {
    $(this).data('success-callback', 'window.mySuccessFunction');
});
```

здесь `$` – экземпляр jQuery, а `'.js-form-proccess'` – (CSS-подобный) селектор, означающий "элементы с классом `js-form-proccess`". Для каждого такого элемента (`this` внутри функции-обработчика) задаётся jQuery-data-свойство `success-callback` (не нужно вдаваться в то, что это такое, важно лишь, что туда надо поместить свой callback, а движок Тильды его подхватит).

Откуда берутся элементы с классом `js-form-proccess`? Видимо, Тильда генерит их для каждой формы; как именно (на сервере или динамически на фронте) и по какому условию – не вполне понятно, доки про это вроде ничего не говорят.

Для начала нужно разобраться с тем, генерируются ли элементы `js-form-proccess` или нет (посмотреть через DOM-инспектор). Если да, может оказаться, что проблема неправильном порядке во времени: Тильда подразумевает, что он будет

1. создаются элементы `js-form-proccess`
2. навешиваются обработчики
3. Тильда обходит элементы в поисках обработчиков (возможно, уже когда запрос в основной сборщик вернул ответ) и запускает их

Если 2. оказался до 1. или после 3. – обработчик не будет запущен.